# Correct Format for customer_id in GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest Using Google Ads Python Client

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-ads-api

I am using the Google Ads Python client in a Google Cloud Function and encountering a TypeError when constructing a GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest. The error message is:

TypeError: Invalid constructor input for GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest: customer_id: "**********"

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import google.ads.googleads.client


def main(request):

    # Get the request arguments from the request
    request_args = request.args

    # If no request args, return error
    if not request_args:
        return 'Error: No request_args provided. Please specify a seed_keyword or page_url.'

    # If no seed keyword or page URL, return error
    if 'seed_keyword' not in request_args and 'page_url' not in request_args:
        return 'Error: No seed_keyword or page_urls field provided. Please specify a seed_keyword or page_url.'

    # Set the default values
    seed_keyword = None
    page_url = None
    location = 'US'
    language = 'EN'
    search_volume = False
    size = 100

    # Get the values from the request
    if 'seed_keyword' in request_args:
        seed_keyword = request_args['seed_keyword']
    elif 'page_url' in request_args:
        page_url = request_args['page_url']
    if 'location' in request_args:
        location = request_args['location']
    if 'language' in request_args:
        language = request_args['language']
    if 'search_volume' in request_args:
        # parse the search_volume value to a boolean
        if request_args['search_volume'] == 'true':
            search_volume = True
        else:
            search_volume = False
    if 'size' in request_args:
        size = request_args['size']

    # Get the keywords from the API
    keywords = generate_keyword_ideas(
        seed_keyword, page_url, location, language, search_volume, size)

    # Return the keywords
    return {'data': keywords}


def generate_keyword_ideas(keyword_text=None, page_url=None, location=None, language=None, search_volume=False, size=100):
    
    customer_id = '**********'
    
    dict_env = {
        "developer_token": '**********',
        "client_id": '**********',
        "client_secret":  '**********',
        "refresh_token":  '**********',
        "customer_id":  customer_id,
        "use_proto_plus": False
    }


    location_ids = [format_location(location)]
    language_id = format_language(language)

    if keyword_text:
        keyword_text = [keyword_text]


    client = (google.ads.googleads.client.GoogleAdsClient
              .load_from_dict(dict_env))
    keyword_plan_idea_service = client.get_service("KeywordPlanIdeaService", version="v13")

    keyword_annotation = client.get_type(
        "KeywordPlanKeywordAnnotationEnum").KEYWORD_CONCEPT
    keyword_plan_network = (
        client.enums.KeywordPlanNetworkEnum.GOOGLE_SEARCH_AND_PARTNERS)
    location_rns = _map_locations_ids_to_resource_names(client, location_ids)
    language_rn = client.get_service(
        "GoogleAdsService").language_constant_path(language_id)

    # Either keywords or a page_url are required to generate keyword ideas
    # so this raises an error if neither are provided.
    if not (keyword_text or page_url):
        raise ValueError(
            "At least one of keywords or page URL is required, "
            "but neither was specified."
        )

    request = client.get_type("GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id

    request.geo_target_constants.extend(location_rns)
    request.language = language_rn
    request.include_adult_keywords = False
    request.keyword_plan_network = keyword_plan_network
    request.keyword_annotation.extend([keyword_annotation])

    if not keyword_text and page_url:
        request.url_seed.url = page_url

    if keyword_text and not page_url:
        request.keyword_seed.keywords.extend(keyword_text)

    if keyword_text and page_url:
        request.keyword_and_url_seed.url = page_url
        request.keyword_and_url_seed.keywords.extend(keyword_text)

    keyword_ideas = keyword_plan_idea_service.generate_keyword_ideas(
        request=request)

    # check if search volume - and return 2 dimensional array [keyword, search_volume]
    if search_volume:
        keywords = [[keyword.text, keyword.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches]
                    for keyword in keyword_ideas]

    else:
        keywords = [keyword.text for keyword in keyword_ideas]

    if keywords:
        keywords = keywords[:size]

    return keywords


def map_keywords_to_string_values(client, keyword_text):
    keyword_protos = []
    for keyword in keyword_text:
        string_val = client.get_type("StringValue")
        string_val.value = keyword
        keyword_protos.append(string_val)
    return keyword_protos


def _map_locations_ids_to_resource_names(client, location_ids):
    build_resource_name = client.get_service(
        "GeoTargetConstantService"
    ).geo_target_constant_path

    return [build_resource_name(location_id) for location_id in location_ids]


###### all locations ids can be found here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/geotargets ######
def format_location(location):
    if location == 'AE':
        location_id = '2784'
    elif location == 'FR':
        location_id = '2250'
    elif location == 'IT':
        location_id = '2380'
    elif location == 'US':
        location_id = '2840'
    elif location == 'ES':
        location_id = '2724'

    return location_id

###### all language ids can be found here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/codes-formats#languages ######
def format_language(language):
    if language == 'EN':
        language_id = '1000'
    elif language == 'AR':
        language_id = '1019'
    elif language == 'FR':
        language_id = '1002'
    elif language == 'ES':
        language_id = '1003'
    elif language == 'IT':
        language_id = '1004'

    return language_id
```

The error occurs when setting customer_id in the GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest. I have verified that the customer_id is a valid 10-digit string. Could there be something wrong with how I am setting up the request or passing the customer_id?